# How to get a one day forward rate from OIS curve?

Tags: fixed-income, forward-curve, ois-swaps

Let's say we have 1 month OIS Rate and a 2 month OIS rate.
How can I construct a 1m1d rate?
Bloomberg computes a lot of these one day rates for several months ahead.
Thank you

Comment: Did you ask the help desk?

Comment: They do not provide prove outs...

Comment: They should show you how it's done though and give you the white paper(s). What have you tried so far? Asking how it's done isn't the same as asking for a complete replication.

Comment: This [question](https://quant.stackexchange.com/q/41208/54838) is essentially identical.